# How to do a partial match of BinarySearch()

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

Im looking at a way of doing a partial match using a binary search. Here is my code:

```
public void checkCardIndexForMatches(List<String> wordsToCheck) throws IOException {
    String[] cardIndexCache = cardIndexCreator.getCardIndexCache();

    for (String text: wordsToCheck){
        int i = Arrays.binarySearch(cardIndexCache, text.getText().toLowerCase().trim());

        if (i > 0){
            text.setCardIndexMatch(true);
        }
        //check if partial match
        //                  else if 
    }
}
```

So its pretty simple stuff so far - there is basically an external file which gets fed in, each line in the file is stored as an array in the cardIndexCache. The problem comes when the user wants to be able to match a 'phrase' in the array (a phrase being more than one word e.g. Mohammed Ali). The words in the wordsToCheck parameter are only passed in as individual words. So the first word will be Mohammed but the binary search fails as it doesnt know what the second word is. I cant think of a simple way of getting the binary search to indicate that a word has the potential to be a match (first part matches, just append the next word and see if that matches).

Any ideas much appreciated!

Comment: Did you know that binarySearch doesn't just return -1 if the item isn't found? It returns -*(the index at which the item would be if it were present)*. If you don't want to actually implement a binary search or a trie yourself, you can probably fake it using that return value.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! i'll give that a go and see how I get on...

Comment: Binary-Search is used in exact-case search .. doing a binary-search on an alphabetically-ordered list of strings is guided by a numerical index, which is an exact-case search in the end .. to do a good search algorithm you build a trie, and do a maximum-common-prefix as an approximation or find another approach which would be more difficult

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a Trie I've written along with a search function that basically finds maximum common prefix, a similarity-search is possible but will be costly ..**

---

```
class TNode
{
    public MapList<Char,TNode> next;

    public TNode ()
    {
        next = new MapList<Char,TNode>();
    }
}
```

---

```
class Trie
{
    TNode head;

    public Trie ()
    {
        head = new TNode();
    }

    public void insert (String t)
    {
        TNode cur = head;

        for (Char c : t.toCharArray())
        {
            if (!cur.next.containsKey(c))
            {
                cur.next.put(c,new TNode());
            }
            cur = cur.next.get(c);
        }
    }

    public boolean remove (String t)
    {
        Stack<Pair<Char,TNode>> path = new Stack<Pair<Char,TNode>>();
        TNode cur = head;
        Pair<Char,TNode> n = null;

        for (Char c : t.toCharArray())
        {
            if (!cur.next.containsKey(c))
            {
                return false;
            }
            path.push(c,cur);
            cur = cur.next.get(c);
        }

        while (path.size() > 0)
        {
            n = path.pop();
            if (n.getSecond().next.get(n.getFirst()).next.size() > 1)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                n.getSecond().next.remove(n.getFirst());
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean search (String t)
    {
        TNode cur = head;

        for (Char c : t.toCharArray())
        {
            if (!cur.next.containsKey(c))
            {
                return false;
            }
            cur = cur.next.get(c);
        }

        return true;
    }

    public String searchMaxPrefix (String t)
    {
        TNode cur = head;
        String match = "";

        for (Char c : t.toCharArray())
        {
            if (cur.next.containsKey(c))
            {
                match += c;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        return match;
    }
}
```